# USB Devices with wine?

Tags: usb, wine, mouse

I have the Redragon M913 Mouse and I wonder if I can use the software on Linux too so I don't have to reboot every time I want to change something in the mouse configurations. It didn't work with wine and said the mouse was disconnected. Is it possible to change something with/within wine to make it detect my mouse? I don't know if it is possible. I read that developers are trying to make the USB support for wine better. I'm not sure what this is really related to and if what other people said is right. Can I install windows drivers for wine to make the mouse software work? I'm pretty much a noob at this point.
I'd be really happy if you can help!

Comment: That would be a question to ask the Wine folks.

Comment: This ^^^ But the general answer is no. Software running under Wine don't have direct access to the hardware, at least not the access level required in this specific case. And due to the way virtualization solutions typically deal with input devices, a Windows VM is no solution either.

Comment: Contrary to the previous comment, I **do** believe that a VM (e.g. VirtualBox) solution will work! But, you have to test and see.

Comment: @FedKad Maybe, with two mice :) Otherwise once you pass the USB mouse to the VM, the host will be left without it and because you bypassed the VirtualBox's mouse integration you'll need to use the keyboard shortcut to toggle the mouse integration (you won't be able to remove the device via the Devices menu)  and at that point the guest may freeze. Not recommended. Knowing the OP has a dual-boot, rebooting to Windows to use the setup software is indeed the best, albeit annoying, solution.

Comment: Okay. The bad thing is that not that many companies care about their customers using Linux. Many of them just make drivers and software for windows. I really wished they would respect us a little more. Hopefully the Linux community will continue to grow and at some point in time we'll get what we deserve.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You are of course right that the host will loose its mouse and this should be expected... I have tested on my notebook and I was able to use the touchpad at the host and the USB mouse in the Windows guest (no mouse pointer for the USB mouse in the guest though!)...

Comment: @FedKad Case in point: *I'm pretty much a noob*... My comment was intended to avoid any unnecessary distress. When something doesn't work with Wine, a Windows VM tends to be automatically suggested as "the next best thing". When I said it's no solution either it was to indicate that for the special case of input devices due to the way hypervisors tend to implement integration there will be many caveats and generally not worth to try (and having a VM just for this purpose is a huge waste of resourses and not necessarily faster than just rebooting to Windows).

Comment: Okay. I understand.